# ARC Project builds OK, multiple warnings when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store, automatic-ref-counting, ios5.1

I released verion 1.0 of my game some months ago. Then, I migrated my game to ARC and developed version 1.1.

May main machine runs Snow Leopard, Xcode 4.2 so I can't target iOS 5.1+ or the New iPad, and I can't upgrade that Mac to Lion or greater because I need some legacy, PowerPC software in it.

So I moved development of my game to another Mac, Mountain Lion, Latest version of Xcode/SDK.
Build/Run, Analyze works fine (Zero Warnings), but when I try to 'Archive' my publishing scheme (Distribution profile, release config, etc.) to submit to the AppStore, I get this warning:

`Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call`

...for **every** source file (.m).

Looks like the project is **building** for ARC but it is **archiving** as if ARC were disabled. How do I fix this? Or should I ignore the warnings and submit the binary?

Any feedback, greatly appreciated...

**NOTE:** I had no problems archiving AdHoc builds on Xcode 4.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I have four build configurations:

1. Debug ('Preinstalled' by Xcode)
2. Release ('Preinstalled' by Xcode)
3. AdHoc (Clone of Release, uses Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile)
4. AppStore (Clone of Release, uses App Store Provisioning Profile)

(I assume everyone does this, but just to be clear)

I found it was the 'AppStore' build configuration that was corrupted: I edited my "Publish" scheme
(usually runs a "Release" build and archives an "AppStore" build) to use the "AppStore" config for the **Run** tab, and I got the same warnings I got when archiving.

So, I deleted the "AppStore" configuration and recreated it by cloning the "Release" configuration once again, (re) set it up to use the App Store distribution profile, and now the project archives for publishing without any issues.

This mess was likely a typical "Xcode project gets corrupted when transfering between machines and/or re-opening with a different version" case.